# get index of the first block of at least n consecutive False values in boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, cumsum

I have a `numpy` boolean array

```
w=np.array([True,False,True,True,False,False,False])
```

I would like to get the index of the first time there are at `n_at_least` false values.
For instance here

```
`n_at_least`=1 -> desired_index=1

`n_at_least`=3 -> desired_index=4
```

I have tried

```
np.cumsum(~w)
```

which does increase every time a `False` value is encountered.
However, when `True` is encountered the counter is not starting from 0 again so I only get the total count of `False` elements rather than the count of the last consecutive ones.

Comment: Why `desired_index=4` when `a_at_least` is 3 ?

Comment: @liliscent I think `n_at_least` is the required number of time `False` occurs. And so the starting index of the sequence where `False` occurs 3 times in a row is 4

Comment: @DavidG Sounds right. I misunderstood to the last index of all `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this linear search operation a python implementation is ok. My suggestion looks like this:

```
def find_block(arr, n_at_least=1):
    current_index = 0
    current_count = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(arr):
         if item:
             current_count = 0
             current_index = index + 1
         else:
             current_count += 1
         if current_count == n_at_least:
             return current_index
    return None # Make sure this is outside for loop
```

Running this function yields the following outputs:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> w = numpy.array([True, False, True, True, False, False, False])
>>> find_block(w, n_at_least=1)
1
>>> find_block(w, n_at_least=3)
4
>>> find_block(w, n_at_least=4)
>>> # None
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a vectorized solution that finds the start, stop indices and hence lengths of *islands* of zeros and finally uses `argmax` to get the starting index of the first island satisfying the criteria of zeros count being `>= n`  -

```
def first_occ_index(w, n):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, w, True])
    lens = np.diff(idx) - 1
    return idx[(lens >= n).argmax()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: w
Out[107]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False])

In [108]: first_occ_index(w, n=1)
Out[108]: 1

In [109]: first_occ_index(w, n=3)
Out[109]: 4
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're falling into the numpy trap of only wanting to use numpy functions. What's wrong with python? This solution is `O(n)`

```
def f(array, n_at_least):
    curr_found_false = 0
    curr_index = 0
    for index, elem in enumerate(array):
        if not elem:
            if curr_found_false == 0:
                curr_index = index
            curr_found_false += 1
            if curr_found_false == n_at_least:
                return curr_index
        else:
            curr_found_false = 0
```

Outputs

```
w=np.array([True,False,True,True,False,False,False])
f(w, 1)
# --> 1
f(w, 3)
# --> 4
```

Comment: Good answer. But I would claim that most people are falling in to the `list` "trap" :). The fact `numpy` is efficient is *because* it's 3rd party.

Comment: @jpp I suppose that's true. But looking for a numpy solution isn't always worth your time for the benefits it brings. That being said I would use one if one is available.

Comment: Just FYI, it can still be done faster using numpy and convolution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747440/13636407

Answer (score 4):

Here is an O(n) numpy solution:

```
>>> def first_consec(A, n):
...     A = np.r_[True, A, True]
...     switch, = np.where(A[:-1]!=A[1:])
...     runs = switch[1::2] - switch[::2]
...     idx = np.argmax(runs >= n)
...     if runs[idx] < n:
...         return None
...     return switch[2*idx]
... 
>>> first_consec(w, 4)
>>> first_consec(w, 3)
4
>>> first_consec(w, 2)
4
>>> first_consec(w, 1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work this way:

```
def n_at_least(n):
    for i in range(len(w)):
         if not any(w[i:i+n]):
             return i
```

However I don't know if there is a better way...

Comment: I like it although you don't need that `break` and this solution is O(n^2). Clean though.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using a generator expression with slicing:

```
w = np.array([True,False,True,True,False,False,False])

n = 2
val = False

res = next((i for i, j in enumerate(w[k:k+n] for k in range(len(w)-n+1)) \
            if np.all(j==val)), None)

# 4
```