# how to implement this array algorithm in a more efficient way?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Assuming I have `n = 3`  lists of same length for example:

`R1 = [7,5,8,6,0,6,7]`

`R2 = [8,0,2,2,0,2,2]`

`R3 = [1,7,5,9,0,9,9]`

I need to find the first index `t` that verifies the **n = 3** following conditions for a period `p = 2`.
Edit: the meaning of period `p` is the number of consecutive "boxes".

- `R1[t] >= 5, R1[t+1] >= 5`. Here `t +p -1 = t+1`, we need to only verify for two boxes `t` and `t+1`. If `p` was equal to `3` we will need to verify for `t`, `t+1` and `t+2`. Note that It's always the same number for which we test, we always test if it's greater than `5` for every index. The condition is always the same for all the "boxes".
- `R2[t] >= 2, R2[t+1] >= 2`
- `R3[t] >= 9, R3[t+1] >= 9`

In total there is **3** * p conditions.

Here the `t` I am looking for is `5` (indexing is starting from 0).

The basic way to do this is by looping on all the indexes using a `for` loop. If the condition is found for some index `t` we store it in some local variable `temp` and we verify the conditions still hold for every element whose index is between `t+1` and `t+p -1`. If while checking, we find an index that does not satisfy a condition, we forget about the `temp` and we keep going.

What is the most **efficient** way to do this in Python if I have large lists (like of 10000 elements)? Is there a more efficient way than the for loop?

Comment: You meant period =2 as a two consecutive values, yes?

Comment: @MrNobody33 Yes

Comment: Show an example and mcve. You're looking for more efficient, but I don't see a first order implementation

Answer (score 2):

Since all your conditions are the same (`>=`), we could leverage this.

This solution will work for any number of conditions and any size of analysis window, and no for loop is used.

You have an array:

```
>>> R = np.array([R1, R2, R3]).T                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> R
array([[7, 8, 1],
       [5, 0, 7],
       [8, 2, 5],
       [6, 2, 9],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 2, 9],
       [7, 2, 9]]
```

and you have thresholds:

```
>>> thresholds = [5, 2, 9]
```

So you can check where the conditions are met:

```
>>> R >= thresholds
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

And where they all met at the same time:

```
>>> R_cond = np.all(R >= thresholds, axis=1)
>>> R_cond
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

From there, you want the conditions to be met for a given window.

We'll use the fact that booleans can sum together, and convolution to apply the window:

```
>>> win_size = 2
>>> R_conv = np.convolve(R_cond, np.ones(win_size), mode="valid")
>>> R_conv
array([0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 2.])
```

The resulting array will have values equal to `win_size` at the indices where all conditions are met on the window range.

So let's retrieve the first of those indices:

```
>>> index = np.where(R_conv == win_size)[0][0]
>>> index
5
```

If such an index doesn't exist, it will raise an `IndexError`, I'm letting you handle that.

So, as a one-liner function, it gives:

```
def idx_conditions(arr, thresholds, win_size, condition):
    return np.where(
        np.convolve(
            np.all(condition(arr, thresholds), axis=1),
            np.ones(win_size),
            mode="valid"
        )
        == win_size
    )[0][0]
```

I added the condition as an argument to the function, to be more general.

```
>>> from operator import ge
>>> idx_conditions(R, thresholds, win_size, ge)
5
```

Comment: Hi @paime and welcome! Thanks for the detailed answer, it's awesome :) I have a question, what if I need to pass some `minimal_index` to the function `idx_conditions` and I will look for the `first_index` greater than the `minimal_index` such that the conditions are satisfied. I thinking about a while loop but something needs to vary from one iteration to another.

Comment: Hi @JoffreyL., you're welcome. To implement a `minimal_index`, just add it as an optional parameter : `def idx_conditions(..., minimal_index=0)`, then add `arr = arr[minimal_index:]` as the first line of the function, and eventually add `... + minimal_index` to the returned value.

Comment: Hi @paime, thank you :) Assume that the method couldn't found the index, how to make it return the index of the minimum possible time window for which the conditions are verified?

Comment: @JoffreyL. You can make recursive call. Just try/catch when you get the index: `try: np.where(...)[0][0] except IndexError: return idx_conditions(... win_size-1) if win_size > 1 else False`. Or make it a `while` instead of recursive, to avoid re-evaluation of the `np.all()` line. Also, if you do it like this it means that `minimal_index` is stronger than the `win_size`. So this function will begin to be tricky, you may want to split it.

Comment: @paime Any hint on how to split it? The problem with the idea is that it's not sufficient if the win_size = 100 but the only possible window is for 2 periods, you will have tens of "useless" iterations

Comment: Using a while around the convolution will be faster if `win_size` is not too far for the actual window size that will be found. If you are gonna use it with innapropriate `win_size `, you can use [this `O(n)` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693931/13636407) to search over `R_cond`, by adding a `curr_found_max` and a `curr_index_max`. See [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L0ymuR3z) for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
R1 = [7,5,8,6,0,6,7]

R2 = [8,0,2,2,0,2,2]

R3 = [1,7,5,9,0,9,9]

for i,inext in zip(range(len(R1)),range(len(R1))[1:]):
    if (R1[i]>=5 and R1[inext]>=5)&(R2[i]>=2 and R2[inext]>=2)&(R3[i]>=9 and R3[inext]>=9):
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
5
```

---

**Edit**: Generalization could be:

```
def foo(ls,conditions):
    index=0
    for i,inext in zip(range(len(R1)),range(len(R1))[1:]):
        if all((ls[j][i]>=conditions[j] and ls[j][inext]>=conditions[j])  for j in range(len(ls))):
            index=i
    return index


R1 = [7,5,8,6,0,6,7]

R2 = [8,0,2,2,0,2,2]

R3 = [1,7,5,9,0,9,9]

R4 = [1,7,5,9,0,1,1]

R5 = [1,7,5,9,0,3,3]



conditions=[5,2,9,1,3]
ls=[R1,R2,R3,R4,R5]

print(foo(ls,conditions))
```

Output:

```
5
```

---

And, maybe if the arrays match the conditions multiple times, you could return a list of the indexes:

```
def foo(ls,conditions):
    index=[]
    for i,inext in zip(range(len(R1)),range(len(R1))[1:]):
        if all((ls[j][i]>=conditions[j] and ls[j][inext]>=conditions[j])  for j in range(len(ls))):
            print(i)
            index.append(i)
    return index


R1 = [6,7,8,6,0,6,7]

R2 = [2,2,2,2,0,2,2]

R3 = [9,9,5,9,0,9,9]

R4 = [1,1,5,9,0,1,1]

R5 = [3,3,5,9,0,3,3]

conditions=[5,2,9,1,3]
ls=[R1,R2,R3,R4,R5]

print(foo(ls,conditions))
```

Output:

```
[0,5]
```

Comment: Thanks :),  I will test it against the basic version I described. How could we generalize it if there is `N` resources instead of  `3` with `N` as input?

Comment: With N conditions too, i guess, yes?

Comment: yes but this *N* is not known in advance. I mean I cannot write `if (R1[i]>=a and R1[inext]>=a)&(R2[i]>=b and R2[inext]>=b)&(R3[i]>=c and R3[inext]>=c) ... (RN[i]>=c and RN[inext]>=c)`  Those `...`does not exist. *N* could be 3, 6, 1, whatever.

Comment: your method seems to be the most efficient, I am trying to find a way to generalize it

Comment: thank you :)  Do you have an idea why your solution is more efficient than both mine and the one proposed by @asalimih? I assume this question needs some under-the-hood knowledge of python.

Comment: I don't know how your solution is. I'm not sure why this happens to be honest because I don't know how the functions that @asalimih used are built. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598677/why-list-comprehension-is-much-faster-than-numpy-for-multiplying-arrays): it shows how the creation of multidimensional arrays  is slower than a simple list comprehension. Maybe that could be a reason for why this happens.  For my solution I guess it's faster because of the list comprehension when using `all`. List comprehension are faster in most cases.

Comment: You also could see this helpful links: [Python Performance Tips: Optimizing Loops](https://nyu-cds.github.io/python-performance-tips/08-loops/#:~:text=List%20comprehension%20is%20faster%20because,than%20equivalent%20use%20of%20map%20.), [What are the advantages of NumPy over regular Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists), [Python Lists vs. Numpy Arrays - What is the difference?](https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: For an exact explanation, maybe you could post another question about the performance of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using numpy ,without for loops:

```
import numpy as np
R1 = np.array([7,5,8,6,0,6,7])
R2 = np.array([8,0,2,2,0,2,2])
R3 = np.array([1,7,5,9,0,9,9])
a = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(R1>=5,R2>=2),R3>=9)
np.where(np.logical_and(a[:-1],a[1:]))[0].item()
```

ouput

```
5
```

Edit:
**Generalization**
Say you have a list of lists `R` and a list of conditions `c`:

```
R = [[7,5,8,6,0,6,7],
     [8,0,2,2,0,2,2],
     [1,7,5,9,0,9,9]]
c = [5,2,9]
```

First we convert them to numpy arrays. the reshape(-1,1) converts `c` to a column matrix so that we can use pythons broadcasting feature in the `>=` operator

```
R = np.array(R)
c = np.array(c).reshape(-1,1)
R>=c

output:
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True]])
```

then we perform logical & operation between all rows using `reduce` function

```
a = np.logical_and.reduce(R>=c)
a
output:
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

next we create two arrays by removing first and last element of `a` and perform a logical & between them which shows which two subsequent elements satisfied the conditions in all lists:

```
np.logical_and(a[:-1],a[1:])
output:
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

now np.where just shows the index of the `True` element

```
np.where(np.logical_and(a[:-1],a[1:]))[0].item()
output:
5
```

Comment: Thanks :), any idea how to generalize it for N lists with N as input (it could be 3, 6, 1, whatever)?

Comment: Generalization Added.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)  Do you have an idea why your solution is more efficient than mine but less efficient than the one suggested by @MrNobody33. I assume this question needs some under-the-hood knowledge of python.

Comment: in terms of performance and run time my solution would be  much better in comparison to `for` loop solutions in larger lists because of vectorized operations.

Comment: Yup, I 've just verified it. How about the scaling not by list size but the number of lists? Does the same argument still hold?